# sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, sudo, azure

I have a consistent error on Azure Ubuntu VMs. 
From time to time, sudo for the admin user ( not root ) will stop working giving out the message :

`sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set`

The funny thing is that checking the actually ownership for /usr/bin/sudo shows root:root 
The admin user is still on the sudoers list, nothing changed apparently.

Comment: The owner/group are still correct, but are the permissions, in particular the setuid bit mentioned? Can you share the output of `stat /usr/bin/sudo`?

Comment: I did found out the problem. One particular script was changing ownership on a folder recursively, and inside that folder there was a hard link to /usr/bin/sudo 
The script was doing chown root:root, which didn't change the ownership but reset the setuid flag and locked me away.